How to copy all items within a layer into a new layer whilst maintaining their positions
I know you can do this when holding the SHIFT key. My question is how can I make this the default so I don't need to hold the SHIFT key

Just highlight the layer (or group) in the Layers Panel and hit Command/Ctrl+j (That's a "jay")
This is a shortcut for Layer > New > Layer via Copy.

Hi thanks for the suggestion.

I suggested yesterday that consider to duplicate the layer. I admit that's not copy+paste in place, but duplicates everything to their original coordinates.
Other workarounds:

record and run an action which selects all, copies and pastes into place
have something else than full transparency at the opposite corners of the layer
try the other Shift key of your keyboard. It can still be functional.

